# Easier Version of Backward Lunge

Tags: knee-pain

I am training to [circumumbulate Mount Kailash](http://www.sacred-destinations.com/tibet/mount-kailash), 32 miles of mountain terrain nearly 18,000 feet above sea level. And I understand this will take years!

Training is 5 days a week, Monday and Thursday are rest days.

One of the exercises I am doing is backward lunge. I am at 4 reps, 1 set. For few days I was happy doing this exercise, now it is causing pain on right knee (started late yesterday morning).

This morning when I woke up, I am unable to do this, or other bending exercises, including [Surya Namaskar](http://www.artofliving.org/us-en/yoga/yoga-postures/surya-namaskar-sun-salutation12-poses-leaner-you) (I'm at 72 reps, 12 yoga poses each!)

Now I have to wait a few days till I get better.

Please give alternate exercise to Backward Lunge. Perhaps I can do this till my knees are strong enough to do both Backward and Forward Lunge.

Thank you.

Comment: What equipment do you have available to you?

Comment: @rrirower I have 25lb, 15lb, 10lb and 8lb pair of free-weigh dumbells. And a stationary bike.

Comment: When you do your backwards lunge, are you keeping your knee from going past your foot? And what sort of a weight distribution do you have between your legs?

Comment: Can you link to a video of this movement?

Answer (score 1):

There’s a myriad of exercises that you can do to train your legs and glutes with just dumbbells.  However, I would caution you that changing the exercise may not alleviate your knee pain.

For a change, you can try:

- These two variations of Split Squat movements.   The [first one](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/split-squat-with-dumbbells)
  uses a bench to elevate your rear foot, while the [second one](http://www.muscleandfitness.com/workouts/leg-exercises/videos/dumbbell-split-squat)
  is simply a split legged squat.  Both more closely resemble the
  movement you were doing (lunges).  Each positions your feet on stable
  platforms, so, you may be able to perform them without discomfort. 
  Again, that’s dependent upon you.
- [Goblet Squats](http://breakingmuscle.com/kettlebells/how-to-do-the-perfect-goblet-squat)
  are an additional movement for developing the quads and glutes.